# jQuery to check for multiple strings with HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working on a 'what you see is what you get' application. You code in one box and the output is displayed in another. I need to check if a user has typed specific text within an HTML textarea, and if it's correct is will make a button visible.
So far, when the user types text-align:center; the button is made visible. I can't work out so the user HAS to type 2 sets of text.
So far i have this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){$(".textArea").keyup(function() { // directed at the textArea div tag
     if ($(this).val().indexOf('text-decoration:underline;' && 'text-align:center;') != -1) { // if the text matches those 2 strings 
      $(".continue").css("visibility", "visible"); // make button visible
    }
      else {
                $(".continue").css("visibility", "hidden"); // keep it hidden if strings haven't been produced
          $(".correct").css("display", "block");
           }
  });
});
```

```css
.continue{
background-color: #ef6d3b;
width: 6em;
text-align: center;
font-size: 15px;
border: none;
height: 25px;
color: #000000;
outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="codeArea">
            <div class="correct">
            <textarea class="textArea">
                <html>
                    <body>
                    
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </body>
                </html>
                
                
 
            </textarea>
                </div>
            
        </div>

 <a href="task2.php"><button class="continue" type="button">Continue</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong expression for your if statement..

> if ($(this).val().indexOf('text-decoration:underline;' &&
>   'text-align:center;') != -1)

which is evaluated same as

> $(this).val().indexOf('text-align:center;') != -1

what you should really do is

> $(this).val().indexOf('text-decoration:underline;')!=-1 &&
>   $(this).val().indexOf('text-align:center;')!=-1

Comment: Thank you so much!! it worked. Just needed to add a bracket at the beginning before the $ and one right at the end after the 1